# cognitoSync data being wiped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

My app uses AWS Cognito to store user preferences.

Users are authenticated and their preferences stored.
When users log out their Cognito dataset is present on the AWS server

But when they log back in all dataset fields are wiped when the app first synchronises.

When `dataset.synchronize()` returns then the data on the AWS server has been deleted. What mis-step I have made?

```
var cognitoDS:AWSCognitoDataset?
…

func getCognitoDataset() -> AWSCognitoDataset? {

    if cognitoDS == nil {
        if let cognitoSync = AWSCognito.defaultCognito() {
            if let cognitoDS = cognitoSync.openOrCreateDataset(Constants.CognitoUserDataset) {
                self.cognitoDS = cognitoDS
            } else {
                print("openOrCreateDataset() returned nil")
            }

        } else {
            print("cognitoSync not found")
        }
    }
    return cognitoDS
}

func synchronizeCognitoDS() -> AWSTask {
    if let dataset = getCognitoDataset() {
        return dataset.synchronize().continueWithBlock { task in
            if let error = task.error {
                NSLog("Error in sync: %@", error.localizedDescription)
                return task
            }

            if task.completed {
                NSLog("Sync successful")
            }

            return task
        }
    }
    return AWSTask(error:NSError(domain:"Juno", code:3030, userInfo:nil))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean your users have data synchronized, but when they call synchronize, they get nothing back? My best guess is you're using unauthenticated users, and either the device is different or the identity has since changed. Cognito can't know data belongs to a user definitively unless they are authenticated, so if it's a different device or the identity has changed (uninstall/reinstall, local storage cleared...etc.), the data gets lost.

Can you clarify what you mean by logged out and logged back in?That'd help narrow this down and confirm/disprove my above thought.

Comment: all my users are authenticated. there is no unauthenticated option. I've used auth0 as my Cognito "wrapper" and call A0Lock.clearSessions() to logout. After this 'logout' step the data is still present on my AWS server. It's removed when the user next logs in.

Comment: And you're 100% sure the identity id is the same when the log out and when the log in happens? Can you confirm that?

Comment: 100% sure. I've an app instance on AWS that only has one Cognito Identity Id so it's easy to spot any oddities in this area.

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry for all the questions, just trying to narrow it down. How are you confirming the sync is successful? Can you see it in the console after it works on the user initially?

Comment: I appreciate all the questions (and your time). Yes, I'm using the console to check the values after a Cognito sync. A breakpoint in my App enables me to step line by line to double-check when it happens. It looks like the App's "empty" fields are overwriting those on the server rather than the App's being over-written by the server's copy.

Comment: What does your sync callback look like? That should be getting invoked in this case.

Comment: It was my error. I'd called `AWSCognitoDataset.clear()` thinking that would clear the local cache. But when the app resumed the logged and sync'd it'd wipe the entries on the server